# array is empty as soon as i loop over it using the this keyword

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have an array that is populated with objects , and when i loop over it using the this keyword , i get a empty array, the peice of code is below:

```
for(var i =0, j = this.data.length ; i < j ; i++) {
            var cur = this.date[i];
            var bubble = this.createBubble(width , this.year.min , cur.start , cur.end );

            /* Add data-duration once i have that figured it out */
            var line = [
                '<span style="margin-left: ' + bubble.getStartOffset() + 'px; width: ' 
                + bubble.getWidth() + 'px; " class="bubble bubble-' + (cur.type || 'default' ) +  '"></span>',
                '<span class="label">'+ cur.text +'<span>'           
            ].join('');

            html.push('<li>'+  line  +'</li>')  
        }
```

See the secound line `var cur = this.date[i];` , if i add a breakpoint to this line of code , and in the console, if i do `this.data` , i do get an array of objects , but when i hover over `this.data[i]`(in the source tab) , `data` seems to be empty , any idea WHY ? my script is getting stuck here because of this error.

**Recreating the bug**
You can see this error **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/timesheet.js/reverse.html)** , go to the source tab in chrome and open reverse.js and add a breakpoint to line 29 ... now reload , you'll see what i described above.

So to repeat my question, why is `this.data[i]` empty ? does this have something with `this` loosing its context , i don't think so , but still asking ?

Comment: `this.data  !==  this.date`

Comment: It should be `var cur = this.data[i];` not `var cur = this.date[i];`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't you mistake?
You say about `this.data[i]`, but in your code i see `var cur = this.date[i];`

Comment: this.date[i] should raise an error tho, or maybe date is also defined as an array somewhere else before this code!

Comment: @SecularKid It does (at least the site linked in the question). `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @Andreas Ok, had not checked the link, so I guess this is the answer x)